# Cannot access state object property

Tags: reactjs

In the state I have an object a with a propertyA. The propertyA is an array. I console.log in the render the object a I can see propertyA with values. When I try to console.log a.propertyA I get undefined, but on rendering the view with the same data in this.state.a, it works. How can I access propertyA on the first render?

```
  const A = this.state.a;
  console.log( A,  A.financial);

  // gives out

   {a: [{...}, {...}, {...}]}, undefined
```

Comment: Your code and the console output doesn't make much sense, can you add some more code

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, I added more infos

Answer (score 1):

```
 const A = this.state.a;
  console.log( a,  A.financial);

  // gives out

   {a: [{...}, {...}, {...}]}, undefined
```

> from the above code it seems that, `this.state.a` is an  Array of
>   objects. `A.financial` will be `undefined` as `financial` is not
>   property of `A`

```
console.log( a,  A[0].financial);// should have output where 0 is array index.
console.log(A.hasOwnProperty('financial))//should be false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my example was incorrect, I updated it to console.log( A,  A.financial);  My this.state.a is an object, it has propertyA as property. So your answer does not work for this case Do you you know how to fix it?

Comment: I now realized, that my code is working if I render the view with the same data. Maybe it is a setState issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the data were fetched via a promise. The promise was not correct. That'S why the state was set before all data were available.